# Copy chosen cells to another column

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have data set from SAP system.
The data structure looks bad.
Data looks like below.
Each value is separated by 4 rows which contain data for other columns.
What I need to do is to copy the cell and paste it to the proper column then go back and copy another value B which is 4 rows under A etc.

```
A



B



C
```

I tried to develop code but it does not work properly.
Could you please look at the code and suggest me something?

```
Sub Create_table()

Dim R As Long
Dim R2 As Long
R = 2
R2 = 7
Range("B7").Select

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.Copy
    Cells(R, 16).PasteSpecial
    Cells(R2 + 4, 2).Copy
    Cells(R + 1, 16).PasteSpecial
    
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: This is really hard to answer, do you have a better representation of the data? Like a screenshot?

Comment: Sure, I'll upload it now.

Comment: @skin please check the picture.

Comment: The good old SAP list reports, terrible things to output and work with.

Comment: Are there consistently one item per purchase req.?

Comment: Hi, it's done now :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not iterating the values

and all the copy paste have to be inside the while

```
Sub Create_table()

Dim R As Long
Dim R2 As Long
R = 2
R2 = 7

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
  Cells(R2, 2).Copy
  Cells(R, 16).PasteSpecial
  R = R + 1
  R2 = R2 + 4
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to change `ActiveCell.Value` to `Cells(R2, 2).Value`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's consistent that there are 4 lines between each record, then this approach will work with formulas.

Cell **P2** = `=OFFSET($B$6,(ROW()-2) * 4,0)`

... and fill down.

**B6** is where your first value is and the formula expects to start in the second row.